# Pass value of textbox to formula

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to pass the value of a textbox to a formula in VBA (Excel)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim min As Integer
Dim max As Integer

min = Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value)
max = Val(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value)

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=RandBetween(Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value),Val(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value))"

End Sub
```

I would like to set a random number in the area between min(textbox3) and max(textbox4).

Unfortunatlly I am not able to pass the value from the textbox to:

```
"=RandBetween(xxxx,xxx)"
```

The output in Excel:

```
=RandBetween(Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value),Val(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value))
```

It seems that the formula does not get the integer values. If I try

```
=RandBetween(4,5)
```

directly in VBA - it works.

I tried to store the value in the variables (min, max) [as you see]

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the textbox references out of the quotes as Excel won't know what they mean. This code won't work if column A is empty.

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=RandBetween(" & Val(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) & "," & Val(UserForm1.TextBox4.Value) & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You deserve a medal. 

The empty Cell is for another purpose